# create trigger for updating one column in table

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

I have two tables : `courses` and `courses_partners`. In table courses I have features of particular course and also field "public". In courses_partners I have `course_id`, `partner_id` , which are foreign keys (relation for M:N). I want to set "public" field in courses table to "n" when count of rows in `courses_partners` where `course_id=1`(for example) is `maxAmount`(what is read from database :

```
SELECT maxAmount FROM courses WHERE course_id=1
```

for example. I have to do it in mysql database with trigger.

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: how to create trigger? I have something like this :                                           CREATE TRIGGER trigger_course_close ON courses_partners
AFTER INSERT ON
BEGIN

DECLARE P1,P2 INT(11);

 SELECT maxAmount INTO P1 FROM courses WHERE course_id=NEW.course_id;
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P2 FROM courses_partners WHERE course_id=NEW.course_id;

 IF P1=P2 THEN
 UPDATE courses SET public='n' WHERE course_id=NEW.course_id; 

END IF;
END; -- but this not working :(

Comment: respektive nieco take: CREATE TRIGGER trigger_course_close

AFTER INSERT ON courses_partners

BEGIN

​
DECLARE P1,P2 INT(11);

​
    SELECT maxAmount INTO P1 FROM courses WHERE course_id=NEW.course_id;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P2 FROM courses_partners WHERE course_id=NEW.course_id;

​

    IF P1=P2 THEN

    UPDATE courses SET public='n' WHERE course_id=NEW.course_id; 

END IF;
END;

Comment: don't paste code blocks into comments. they're unreadable garbage. you can edit your question.